# Can't send message with russian symbols with Telegram Bot

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I made simple php bot for telegram which reply to me with a message.
Code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

function SendMessage($message){
    global $website, $chatId;
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$message);
}

$botToken = "my token";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, TRUE);
$message = $update["message"];

$chatId = $message["chat"]["id"];
$text = $message["text"];

if ($text == "/start") {
    SendMessage("welcome, it's nice to meet you");
} else {
    SendMessage("сори");
}
```

And everything was alright, but at some point my bot stopped working. I started debug it by deleting everything that works. And i found interesting result.

1. In my first try bot didn't send anything. Message got both russian and english symbols.
2. In second i delete russian symbols and it worked.
3. BUT in third i put one russian word and it also worked.
4. BUTx2 when i used exact word from first try bot didn't do anything.

[images of results to make it clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i85bz.png)

Please explain to me how it is possible. And how to solve it.

UPDATE. My script is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: What's the encoding of your script?

Comment: encoding is UTF-8

Comment: Welcome to PHP Unicode support

Comment: Use this $string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);

Comment: I’d try applying proper URL-encoding …

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your advices.
I solved it by making proper URL-encoding. I just by added [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) function:

```
function SendMessage($message){
    global $website, $chatId;

    $message = urlencode($message);

    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$message);
}
```